# unoconv fails to save in my specified directory

Tags: libreoffice

I am using unoconv to convert an ods spreadsheet to a `csv file`.

Here is the command:

```
unoconv -vvv --doctype=spreadsheet --format=csv --output= ~/Dropbox 
/mariners_site/textFiles/expenses.csv ~/Dropbox/Aldeburgh/expenses
/expenses.ods
```

It saves the output file in the same directory as the source file, not in the specified directory.  The error message is:

```
Output file: /home/richard/Dropbox/mariners_site/textFiles/expenses.csv
unoconv: UnoException during export phase:
Unable to store document to file:///home/richard/Dropbox/mariners_site
/textFiles/expenses.csv (ErrCode 19468)
```

I'm sure that this worked initially, but it has since stopped.

I have checked for permissions and they are identical for both directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translated ErrCode **19468** for you and it boils down to meaning **ERRCODE_SFX_DOCUMENTREADONLY**.

You can find more information about the specific meaning of LibreOffice ErrCode numbers from the unoconv documentation at: https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/doc/errcode.adoc

The clue here is that you have a whitespace-character between **--output=** and the filename (--output= ~/Dropbox 
/mariners_site/textFiles/expenses.csv) and because of that unoconv gets an empty output value (which means the current directory) and is given 2 files. And that explains why you get this specific error IMO